# Variables within an object

Tags: javascript, variables, object

I was reading a script and noticed that the programmer who wrote it had declared all their variables within an object. Example:

```
var variables = {
    height : window.innerHeight,
    width : window.innerWidth,
    image : 'img/image.png'
}
```

Why would one set their variables out like this instead of the traditional method (as seen below)?

```
var height = window.innerHeight,
    width = window.innerWidth,
    image = 'img/image.png';
```

Comment: Maybe to pass every variables into a method => method(variables);

Comment: Creates one object with 3 attributes.in second case, creates three different variables.

Comment: Would depend on the context.

Comment: Traditional method will take memory during compile time. Why not do runtime binding via Object and save memory and increase efficiency. What you will prefer Runtime or Compile time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the usage.

Perhaps the programmer wants to pass the fields `height`, `width` and `image` into a function, so he placed these variables inside an object to pass it as one parameter.

so instead of doing this

```
function doSomething(height, width, image) {
    // do something
}
```

he can do this

```
function doSomething(imageObject) {
     // do something
}
```